# Count number of comparisons in binary search tree

Tags: c, recursion, comparison, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I would like to count the number of comparisons needed to find data in binary search tree.
So far I have function that checks whether data is in the tree. I am confused about how to count comparisons because function is recursive. Do I need to use global variable for that? But in this case it will remain the same all the time and I cannot use it second time. Thanks!

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int Titem;
typedef struct node* Tpointer;
typedef struct node{
    Titem item;
    Tpointer left;
    Tpointer right;
}Tnode;
typedef Tpointer TBinSTree;

void initialize(TBinSTree* bintree);
void insert_to_tree(TBinSTree* bintree, Titem item);
int isInTree(TBinSTree* bintree, Titem item, int* counter);
void print_tree(TBinSTree bintree);

#include "bintree.h"

void initialize(TBinSTree* bintree){
    *bintree = NULL;
}
void insert_to_tree(TBinSTree* bintree, Titem newitem){
    Tpointer newnode = *bintree;
    if (*bintree == NULL){// if tree is empty
        newnode = (Tpointer)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
        newnode->left = NULL;
        newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->item = newitem;
        *bintree = newnode;
    }
    else{
        if (newnode->item > newitem)
            insert_to_tree(&newnode->left, newitem);
        if (newnode->item < newitem)
            insert_to_tree(&newnode->right, newitem);
    }
}
int isInTree(TBinSTree* bintree, Titem item, int* counter){
    Tpointer current = *bintree;
    (*counter)++;
    if (current == NULL){// Base case == empty tree
        printf("Item %d is not in the tree\n", item);
        printf("Number of comparisons (case NULL) is: %d\n", *counter);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        if (current->item == item){ //see if found here
            printf("Item %d is in the tree\n", item);
            printf("Number of comparisons (case node.item == item) is: %d\n", *counter);
            return 0;
        }
        else{ //otherwise recur down the correct subtree
            if (item < current->item)
                return isInTree(&current->left, item, counter);
            else
                return isInTree(&current->right, item, counter);
        }
    }
}
void print_tree(TBinSTree bintree){ // inorder traverse
    if (bintree != NULL) {
        print_tree(bintree->left);
        printf("%d\n", bintree->item);
        print_tree(bintree->right);
    }
}

#include "bintree.h"
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBERS 10000

int main(void){

    srand(time(NULL));
    TBinSTree tree;
    int item_to_search;
    int count = 0;

    initialize(&tree);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS; i++){
        insert_to_tree(&tree, rand() % 10000);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        count = 0;
        printf("Input %d item to search: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &item_to_search);
        isInTree(&tree, item_to_search, &count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD1**
I have updated code but now NULL case print statement is called twice.
**UPD2**
This is final version of code that works perfectly for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also pass around a reference to the counter when you call it, e.g.

```
int isInTree(TBinSTree* bintree, Titem item, int* counter)
{
    ...
    if (counter != null)
    {
        (*counter)++;
        printf("Number of comparisons is %d\n", *counter);
    }
    ...
        return isInTree(&tmp->left, item, counter);
    ...
}

int counter = 0;
isInTree(foo, bar, &counter);
```

passing it into the next recursions: that way you can use different counter variables for different calls to the function.

Comment: this is good point, thanks! But what if I want to print counter inside the function and not in main?

Comment: You'll need to use `*counter` to dereference the number again for that - yes. I've added that into my code. BTW I suspect you only really care about one comparison per iteration: I don't think the null check counts, and you can probably consider comparing the item and current node's item as a single comparison too. In which case you're effectively just counting the depth of the tree you recurse to.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
int isInTree(TBinSTree* bintree, Titem item){

    Tpointer tmp = *bintree;
    counter++;
    if (tmp == NULL){// Base case == empty tree
        printf("Number of comparisons is: \n", counter);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        counter++;
        if (tmp->item == item){ //see if found here
            printf("Number of comparisons is: \n", counter);
            return 0;
        }
        else{ //otherwise recur down the correct subtree
            counter++;
            if (item < tmp->item)
                return isInTree(&tmp->left, item);
            else
                return isInTree(&tmp->right, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Use global variable and set it to `0` while calling once again the search function.

```
counter = 0;
isInTree(...); //call to search
//print counter variable.


counter = 0;
isInTree(...); //another call to search
//print counter variable.
```

Comment: If he uses more than one thread, this will give biased results.